# Magento - migrating customer and order history to different store

Tags: php, magento

Is there any possibility to move customer and order data between 2 magento sites?

I have a database which keeps giving wierd issues with the database so I intend to rebuild the site, adding in some extra features at the same time.  I cannot loose the order and customer history though (including passwords etc) so Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. I posted a question about this in the magento [forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/279474/).

If i don't get an satisfying answer, i will write an application that reads and associates the customers and orders and writes both into the new store.

You can do that using the Magento SOAP API.